# Post Request API with SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I wanted to create a stored procedure in SQL Server to complete a `POST` request. The request would take two parameters.

Curl that I've used for Postman:

```
curl -X 'POST' \
  'https://link' \
  -H 'accept: application/json' \
  -H 'Authorization: Bearer somepassword' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -d '{
  "userName": "username",
  "password": "password"
}'
```

I've tried writing the code below, but it doesn't seem to work...

```
DECLARE @token INT;
DECLARE @ret INT;
DECLARE @url NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @apiKey NVARCHAR(32);

DECLARE @json AS TABLE(Json_Table NVARCHAR(MAX))

DECLARE @userName varchar(max)              
DECLARE @password varchar(max)
DECLARE @body     varchar(max)

SET @url = 'https://link'
SET @userName = 'username'
SET @password = 'password'

SET @body = '
{
  "userName": "'+@username+'",
  "password": "'+@password+'"
}
'
EXEC @ret = sp_OACreate 'MSXML2.XMLHTTP', @token OUT;

IF @ret <> 0 
     RAISERROR('Unable to open HTTP connection.', 10, 1);

-- This calls the necessary methods.
EXEC @ret = sp_OAMethod @token, 'open', NULL, 'GET', @url, 'false';
EXEC @ret = sp_OAMethod @token, 'send', null, @body

-- Grab the responseText property, and insert the JSON string into a table temporarily. This is very important, if you don't do this step you'll run into problems.

INSERT INTO @json (Json_Table) 
    EXEC sp_OAGetProperty @token, 'responseText'

-- This is all I have to add to insert into a non-existing table.
SELECT * 
FROM OPENJSON((SELECT * FROM @json))
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend against using the legacy, hard-to-use OA procedures.  Instead, this is a task for a .NET library via SQLCLR.  For years I have used [this](https://github.com/eilerth/sqlclr-http-request) library to handle API calls from the database.

Comment: Couldn't add the assembly, It is impossible to load a mixed mode C++/CLI assembly into SQL Server.

Do you have any other approach? Thank you!

Comment: The linked library uses C# and not C++.  I'm not sure what your issue.  I've loaded this library into various SQL servers.  I don't recall specifically for this library, but you may need to work around the `clr strict security` setting in SQL 2017+.  For testing it is easiest to just disable this using `sp_configure`.